# How can I configure metro to resolve modules outside of my project directory?

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

For reasons that are out of my control, I need to resolve a module that is outside of my react-native project directory. So, consider the following directory structure:

```
react-native-project/
├─ App.jsx
├─ babel.config.js
external-directory/
├─ Foo.jsx
```

I would like any `import Foo from 'Foo'` inside of `react-native-project` to resolve `../external-directory/Foo.jsx`. My first attempt at this was to use `babel-plugin-module-loader` with the following configuration:

```
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        alias: {
          Foo: '/absolute/path/to/external-directory/Foo',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
```

This doesn't work, with metro emitting the following error:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module /absolute/path/to/external-directory/Foo from /absolute/path/to/react-native-project/App.jsx: 

None of these files exist:
  * ../external-directory/Foo(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * ../external-directory/Foo/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

This error message is wrong: `../external-directory/Foo.jsx` does exist. I've verified this numerous times. I've also set up a standalone babel package to test an identical import scenario, and babel correctly resolves the external module.

The other approach I took was to add a custom `resolveRequest` function in my metro.config.js:

```
const defaultResolver = require('metro-resolver').resolve;

module.exports = {
  ...
  resolver: {
    resolveRequest: (context, moduleName, platform, realModuleName) => {
      if (moduleName === 'Foo') {
        return {
          filePath: '/absolute/path/to/external-directory/Foo.jsx',
          type: 'sourceFile',
        };
      } else {
        return defaultResolver(
          {
            ...context,
            resolveRequest: null,
          },
          moduleName,
          platform,
          realModuleName,
        );
      }
    },
  },
};
```

This also doesn't work, emitting the following error message:

```
error: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /absolute/path/to/external-directory/Foo.jsx (/absolute/path/to/external-directory/Foo.jsx) is not computed.
         Potential causes:
           1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
           2) Check `blockList` in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.
```

The potential causes do not apply in this scenario: There are no symlinks nor does the blockList contain the external directory (I explicitly configured `blockList: null` to verify).

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Or does metro (either by design or incidentally) prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried this setting https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration/#nodemodulespaths?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a metro bundler build in option - extraNodeModules and watchFolders.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    ...,
    extraNodeModules: {
      app: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../app')
    }
  },
  ...,
  watchFolders: [
    path.resolve(__dirname + '/../app')
  ]
};
```

Comment: I just checked, it is only necessary to add this metro config, no need to add babel plugins, like the OP tried. If you are using TypeScript you will also need to add `paths` in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: When resolving paths you are supposed to write them with commas `path.resolve(__dirname, '../app')` and let the path module merge them for you