# module-resolver is not resolving path in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, babeljs

this is the file structure:

```
app
 - (authenticate)
   - login
   - register
 - services
   - authentication
     - authentication.context.tsx
```

this is the `babel.config..js`

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      // Required for expo-router
      "expo-router/babel",

      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          extensions: [
            ".ios.js",
            ".android.js",
            ".ios.jsx",
            ".android.jsx",
            ".js",
            ".jsx",
            ".json",
            ".ts",
            ".tsx",
          ],
          root: ["."],
          alias: {
            // --- tried both ----
            // "@services": "/app/services/",
            "@services/*": ["app/services/*"],
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

I have this error

```
Unable to resolve "@services/authentication/authentication.context" from "app/(authenticate)/login.tsx"

// app/(authenticate)/login.tsx
import { AuthenticationContext } from "@services/authentication/authentication.context";
```

`tsconfig.json` config is correct. I do not get typescript error but `babel.config` error. I am on `debian linux` and have those installed

```
"react-native": "0.72.6",
"expo": "~49.0.15",
```

Comment: Aren't paths something that you should configure in tsconfig ? https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/typescript babel and ts config are different

Comment: I know they are different, it's just odd that you didn't include it, since it is necessary to configure tsconfig paths to avoid errors from typescript's side

Comment: Anyway I found an identical question, which luckily for you already has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74032259

Comment: did you resolve it?@Yilmaz  I have a similar issue :                                                                  Unable to resolve "react-hook-form" from "src\screens\authScreens\loginScreen\LoginScreen.tsx"

Comment: @mermaid not yet. currently using full path to make progress